# Can XSLT perform an XML-decode and then process the result?

Tags: xslt

I have this input XML that looks conceptually something like this:

```
<x>
    <a>a text</a>
    <b datamodel="&lt;y>&#xA;    &lt;a>a text&lt;/a>&#xA;    &lt;b>someone's text>&lt;/b>&#xA;&lt;/y>" />
</x>
```

The value of datamodel is an XML-encoded string of another piece of XML:

```
<y>
    <a>a text</a>
    <b>someone's text></b>
</y>
```

Note that

1. `>` and `'` are not encoded to `&gt;` and `&apos;` respectively
2. `&#xA;` represents an enter

Is there a way for XSLT to retrieve `datamodel`'s value, perform the decoding and show the value of y.a or y.b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 3 or 3.1 you have the `parse-xml` function so with any XSLT 3 processor or an XSLT 2 processor giving you access to XPath 3 functions you can do e.g. `parse-xml(@datamodel)/y/(a, b)`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="b[@datamodel]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="parse-xml(@datamodel)/y/(a, b)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7kW uses Saxon 9.8 which implements XSLT 3, Altova 2017 and later also do that, I think that earlier versions of Saxon (9.7 at least) already supported the `parse-xml` function, as I think XmlPrime 4 does.

Of course with other or older XSLT 1 or 2 processor there is often a proprietary way to use an extension function, even MSXML 3 or 6, an XSLT 1 processor, would allow that as long as `msxsl:script` is enabled.

Comment: @zx485, you are right, although the essential `parse-xml(@datamodel)/y/(a, b)` is in there, I somehow forgot to include the XSLT example over pondering which version of Saxon 9 first supported that function although it did not support XSLT 3. Will edit.